# Xcode: Posting video from device album into Facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, sharing, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have developed an application that has sharing function on Facebook. The program executes fine but I have two issues which is:

(i) How do i redirect the function to open in Facebook app and not in browser.
(ii) How to select pictures/videos from device album and post it into Facebook.

I could not find proper guidance into solving this 2 issues. I have tried few tutorials online but nothing seem to work. Can someone guide me to solve this? Thank you.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL
                        URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"];

FBSDKShareLinkContent *imageURL = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
imageURL.imageURL = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_ Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg"];



FBSDKShareButton *shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];


shareButton.shareContent = content;
shareButton.shareContent = imageURL;
shareButton.center = self.view.center;

[self.view addSubview:shareButton];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any help and suggestion is much appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by FABSharedialog or convert the video into nsdata then post to facebook.The latest facbook SDK is FBCorekit, facbook developer site gives all information and sample code , which can help you.